# How do I apply an actionListener to the title of a TitledBorder?

Tags: java, swing, border, listener, actionlistener

I have a question regarding the usage of actionListener for the title of a TitledBorder:

```
borderPanel1 = BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(
                BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(EtchedBorder.LOWERED),
                MainFrame.windowTitle);
```

My final goal is to be able to press the title of the border to change the title of a panel.
How would I be able to add some kind of Listener to the title of this border?

Comment: Why would the user want/need to be renaming panels?

Answer (score 2):

A titled border really isn't designed for this; it's a `Border`, not a `Component`. If the title is a user preference, the you can add it to your [`Preferences`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/prefs/Preferences.html) dialog.

Answer (score 2):

The authors of [`setBorder()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setBorder%28javax.swing.border.Border%29) "recommend that you put the component in a `JPanel` and set the border on the `JPanel`." You could add a `MouseAdapter` to that `JPanel` and have the chosen handler bring up the `Preferences` dialog, as @Catalina Island suggests.